# Convert PHP Unix Timestamp to Javascript Timestamp format

Tags: javascript, php, unix, timestamp

I'm throwing a unix timestamp from my php to my javascript and I noticed that PHP and Javascript timestamps are different (seconds vs. milliseconds) from the epoch.

What I'm basically doing is to echo the php unixtime then add 3 zeroes (as to simply multiply it by 1000) but I noticed that when I check it, it shows that the time is off by around 4-8 hours.

I am using canvas.js and I need to convert it using the unix timestamp

For example:

> 1434183780
>
> Jun 13 2015 8:23AM

I add 3 zeroes

> 1434183780000

```
echo "{ x:".$chartData[$loop]['time']."000 , y:1 }";
```

and what happens is the time becomes:

> Jun 13 2015 16:23PM

Everything is working fine except that the time becomes completely distorted.

How could I make it work without the time being changed once I put it on javascript? I'd prefer to keep it in unixtime as I still use it in that format when I do something else with it.

Comment: The timestamp is UTC, perhaps local time is getting in the way?

Comment: are your referring to the PHP side or the Javascript side? I checked the PHP side and it is getting the correct data.

Comment: I'm talking about the client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds just like a time zone issue.

A [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is always a point in time in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

When displaying it in a format like "Jun 13 2015 8:23AM" you are always using a certain time zone to display it as such. The reason the time is being displayed as "16:23PM" is because a time zone other than you expect is being used to display the Unix timestamp.

So the solution is simply making sure you're picking the correct time zone when displaying the timestamp.

If you're using the JavaScript `Date` object and you mean to use UTC, you can try using a method like `toUTCString()`:

```
console.log(new Date(1434183780000).toUTCString());
// Output: Sat, 13 Jun 2015 08:23:00 GMT
```

`Date` supports only the local time zone or UTC. If you want to construct your own formatted string in UTC, you can use the methods in `Date` starting with `getUTC*()`, like `getUTCHours()` or `getUTCDate()` .

See more info on the `Date` object in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Also of note is that a JS time is in micro seconds, so its a unix timestamp times 1000

Comment: It's more correct to say that the timestamp for a `Date` object is in milliseconds. JavaScript the language doesn't care about that. As far as I know, `Date` doesn't use anything more precise than _milliseconds_.

I'm aware that microsecond precision is used as a float point number in the method Performance.now(), which is part of the High Resolution Time spec (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance).

Comment: Yes, of course milliseconds... I always get the two backwards! >.< Thanks for correcting me.